# how to add qlabel to a QDialogButtonBox UI file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel, qdialog

I'm trying to write a QGIS plugin and display a help dialogbox with python 3 and Qt5. However, the default dialog box based on `QDialogButtonBox` shows only two standard buttons and no text.

[image]

The `.ui` file has the following:

```
  <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="button_box" >
   <property name="geometry" >
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>240</y>
     <width>341</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation" >
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="standardButtons" >
    <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
```

I'm new to Qt5/pyqt. I tried to add a widget following examples:

```
label = QLabel()
label.setText("Help\n instructions: \n")
self.dlg.addWidget(label)
```

But I got an error: `AttributeError: 'XXXDialog' object has no attribute 'addWidget'`

My question is:

How can I add a `QLabel` or another widget (preferably with a text editor) that can display multiline text to the main area of the dialogbox. Do I have to use a different base class than `QDialogButtonBox`?

Comment: Why don't you just follow the [QGIS Plugin Tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html)? It takes you through the whole process in simple steps, including designing the gui using Qt Creator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to pass as `QLabel` parent to `QDialog`, since in Qt the coordinates of a widget are relative to the parent, then you can change the position with `move()`, to adjust the size of the `QLabel` to its content you must use `adjustSize()`:

```
label = QLabel(self.dlg)
label.setText("Help\n instructions: \n")
label.adjustSize()
label.move(100, 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

QDialog does not have "addWidget" but its layout does.

```
  layout = QVBoxLayout()
  label = QLabel(self.dlg)
  label.setText("Help\n instructions: \n")
  layout.addWidget(label);
  self.dlg.setLayout(layout);
```